How to play left hand with lead sheet on the piano?
I am trying to play lead sheets and I am not sure how to play the chords on the left hand.
At first, I pressed the keys all at the same time once, and now I am trying to arpeggiate the chords.
It may/may not be right, but I have found so far

it sounds nice when playing the 3rd note down/up from the melody
it sounds nice to play non-triadic note (like 7th) when non-chord tone is in the melody,

but I think there must be MUCH more to it,
and if you have any know-hows, could you share?

I’m voting to close this question because this is a huge topic with entire books dedicated to it. The question should be reconsidered so that it fits the simple Q&A format of the site.

There are many, many ways to accompany with l.h. Depending on the song, the tempo, what arrangement the accompanist wants at that time, busy or sparse, what style he uses, who else is playing, etc. etc. No simple  answer, I'm afraid.

The simplest realization of a lead sheet is to play the indicated chord with the right hand and the indicated bass note with the left hand.  The indicated bass note is the same as the root of the chord unless there is a slash followed by a letter, in which case the letter after the slash indicates the bass note.
For example, if the chord is C/E, you play E with the left hand and C-E-G with the right (or E-G-C, or G-C-E).  If the chord is simply C, you play C with the left hand instead.  (You can also omit the bass note in the right hand, and often it is best to do so.)
If you're trying to play the melody and the chords together, then things get a bit more complicated.  You can start by playing the indicated bass note and the melody, omitting the chords entirely, and then figure out whether it makes more sense to add notes from the chord in the right hand or the left.  Normally, closely voiced chords -- notes spaced so they fit under one hand -- should be played in the tenor octave or higher (no more than an octave below middle C), so skillful players will alternate with the left hand between low bass notes on the beat and mid-range chords off the beat.  They will also play chord tones below the melody with the right hand.
If this is beyond your skill at present, you can indeed arpeggiate the chords with the left hand, the right hand, or both.
Specific choices relating to the melody depend on the music -- the specific melody and chords -- and on the style you're trying to achieve.  It won't always sound good to double the melody a third above or below, but it will in probably a large majority of the cases.  Whether using the chordal seventh against a non-chord tone sounds good will similarly depend on the context -- and on the quality of the triad and the identity of the non-chord tone.
In any event, it sounds like you're using your ears and your sense of good taste, and that is a huge factor working in your favor.

A lot of lead sheet interpretation is the rhythm of the chords you play. For example, dotted quarter-dotted quarter-quarter note rhythms for chords is a great idea in a lead sheet of "Libertango" and a terrible idea in a lead sheet of "Blue Rondo a la Turk" (including its 4/4 section).
